# Type variance in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, generics, types, covariance, contravariance

`IEnumerable<T>`, `IComparable<T>` and a few more are now type-variant. `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and many others aren't. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.0 introduces **safe** co/contra-variance. `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` have `T` both in input and output positions while `IEnumerable<T>` has `T` *only in output positions* and `IComparable<T>` has `T` *only in input positions*.

Assume `IList<T>` supported type variance:

```
static void FailingMethod(IList<object> list) {
    list[0] = 5;
}

static void Test() {
    var a = new List<string>();
    a[0] = "hello";
    FailingMethod(a); // if it was variant, this method call would be unsafe
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like using indexers makes any class non-variant.
But ICollection<> has T only in input parameters.

Comment: No, it's not related to indexers in general. It depends on the parameter and return type of indexers (and existence of get/set accessors), just like any other method or property. You might have an indexer like: T this[int index] { get { return x[index]; } } and without a set accessor, it could be variant.

Answer (score 2):

See also: [What C# 4.0 covariance *doesn't* do](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html)

Answer (score 1):

Anders Hejlseberg has a brief, but illuminating discussion that describes co/contravariance in his talk, "The Future of C#."  His discussion on covariance and contravariance starts at 50 minutes and 17 seconds into the presentation.

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/